# printing out each element in a vector of objects C++

Tags: c++

im trying to output the objects that are stored in a vector but i keep getting addresses of those objects instead of the name of the actual object.

```
vector <Shape*> shapes;

for (std::vector<Shape*>::iterator it = shapes.begin(); it != shapes.end(); ++it)
            std::cout << *it << endl;
```

output:

```
Enter the command: display
01724888
017309B0
01731238
```

Example of how an object is stored in shapes:

```
Circle* c = new Circle(x, y, r);
        shapes.push_back(c);
```

Comment: Thinks about it.  If `*it` gives you the element that is in the vector at that position, what is that type that you are getting?

Comment: the elements in the vectors are addresses!

Comment: so when i push back an object to the vector it only stores the address and not the name of the object ?

Comment: It does if you use a `vector <Shape*>`.  The `Shape*` says that the elements of the vector should be `Shape*`'s

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @OpenSourcerer42 There are no names at runtime, unless you store them yourself in string variables

Answer (score 1):

As the elements in your vectors are pointers, `*it` gives you the values of those pointers, but pointers store addresses. If you want to get the value under those addresses, you should use `**it`.
This `Shape` class may print the area, volume, or its dimensions. You should either create a method to `printVolume()` this or an `overloading operator <<`

Sample code

```
#include <iostream>

class Shape 
{
    private:
        int _x, _y, _z;
    public:
        Shape(int x, int y, int z): _x(x), _y(y), _z(z)
        {
        }
        void printVolume()
        {
            std::cout << "Print volume: " << _x * _y * _z << std::endl;
        }

        friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Shape& object)
        {
            std::cout << "Inside overload operator to return the volume" << std::endl;
            out << object._x * object._y * object._z << std::endl;
            return out;
        }
};


int main ()
{
    Shape cube(1, 2, 3);
    std::cout << cube;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are assuming that using operator `<<` on a Shape object makes sense to the compiler. Without an [mre], that is a little daring.

Comment: I get an error on the << operator, would i just have to implement operator overloading to fix that

Comment: See? That is what I meant.

Comment: @OpenSourcerer42 yes, you would need to implement `operator<<` for your `Shape` class

Comment: im not sure how to implement operator<< for a shape vector

Comment: @OpenSourcerer42 -- It is up to you *how* you want your data to be outputted.  You know more about your `Shape` type than we do, and we can't tell you what the best or nicest way to present your output.  However once you determine how you want your output to look, then you implement `operator <<` on your `Shape` type.

Comment: @OpenSourcerer42 the operator << is not a member function - it is a free function.  `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Shape& s) { os << s.x << ', ' << s.y << '\n'; return os; }`  where x and y are members actually in your Shape class.